# Text formatting in TextBlock Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have a list of strings in my `ViewModel` with the following format:

```
 This is an <b>example.<b>
```

I want to have some kind of text control in my view that will display the formatted text via `DataBinding`*, like this:

> This is an **example.**

I don't find any built-in control that can behave like this.

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: See this link, it worked perfectly for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30442559/3934111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run(v=vs.110).aspx):

```xml
<TextBlock FontSize="30">
    <Run>This is an</Run>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text=" example"/>
</TextBlock>
```

For this you will have to parse your strings, select bold sections, and define content in the code behind. A very simple example can look like this:

```cs
string example = @"This is an <b>example.</b>";
var str = example.Split(new string[] { "<b>", "</b>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = str[i], FontWeight = i % 2 == 1 ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal });
```

---

*Edit - using with Binding*

If you want to use the above procedure with Binding, then it's not so simple - *TextBlock.Inlines* is not a *DependencyProperty*, so we cannot use it. Nevertheless there is a way to do it - you need to extend somehow your TextBlock - here is another pitfall - it's *sealed* class so no inheritance. In this case we will have to use another class ([here is also a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7569049/2681948)):

```cs
public static class TextBlockExtension
{
    public static string GetFormattedText(DependencyObject obj)
    { return (string)obj.GetValue(FormattedTextProperty); }

    public static void SetFormattedText(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    { obj.SetValue(FormattedTextProperty, value); }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FormattedText", typeof(string), typeof(TextBlockExtension),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, (sender, e) =>
        {
            string text = e.NewValue as string;
            var textBl = sender as TextBlock;
            if (textBl != null)
            {
                textBl.Inlines.Clear();
                var str = text.Split(new string[] { "<b>", "</b>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                    textBl.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = str[i], FontWeight = i % 2 == 1 ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal });
            }
        }));
}
```

Then you can use it in xaml like this:

```xml
<TextBlock local:TextBlockExtension.FormattedText="{Binding MyText}"/>
```

Comment: I wouldn't remove empty entries.  That would break "this <b></b> should not all be <b>bold</>"

Comment: @ZombieSheep You are right. Nevertheless it's still a very basic exampel and needs more improvemets (it also depend on OP's implementation). This should help the OP, the rest I'll leave to him.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RichTextBlock control. Something like:

```
<RichTextBlock>
 <Paragraph>
    This is an <Bold>example</Bold>
 </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```